# Multi-Column ComboBox in Excel VB

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have some ComboBoxes in a UserForm. One of the ComboBoxes is a multicolumn ComboBox with three columns and is dependent on another ComboBoxs' value.

Does anyone know WHY when I choose one of the lines in the multicolumn combobox shows only **the first column value**?

I want the value from the second column to be visible when I choose a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Combox Property that set which column to *display* in the TextBox portion of the Combobox is `TextColumn`

Property values:

-1 = Display the first column whose width (set by `ColumnWidths` property) is > 0
 0 = Display the value of `ListIndex`
 1 = Display column 1
etc

Comment: Thank u Chris & happy new year.